# How do I get the username and password from a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

The username and password comes from a URL like this:

```
https://theuser:thepassword@localhost:20694/WebApp
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to have their username and password in the url

Comment: use regex to match the user and password and extract from string

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. You won't get the basic authentication credentials, they are handled by the IIS.

Comment: You may use the `Split` function to split on a delimiter. But how safe is to expose the username and pwd in the URL like this. Better use some other strategy.

Comment: Are you after [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)??

Comment: Claudio Redi, that makes sense as everything I've tried is stripping out the credentials before I can read them.

Answer (score 5):

Create a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) and then get the `UserInfo` property:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://theuser:thepassword@localhost:20694/WebApp");
Console.WriteLine(uri.UserInfo); // theuser:thepassword
```

If necessary you can then split on `:`, like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://theuser:thepassword@localhost:20694/WebApp");
var userInfo = uri.UserInfo.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(userInfo[0]); // theuser
Console.WriteLine(userInfo[1]); // thepassword
```

Note that if you're trying to get the current user in the context of an ASP.NET request, it's  better to use the provided APIs, like [`HttpContext.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Or if this is in a web form, just:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "Home page for " + User.Identity.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        Page.Title = "Home page for guest user.";
    }
}
```

As for passwords, I'd recommend you not trying to deal with the passwords directly after the user has been authenticated.

Comment: @matt Since this was tagged as ASP.NET, you may be wanting it from the current URI. In that case, use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` (or in some cases just `Request.Url`) instead of creating a new URI.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = @"https://theuser:thepassword@localhost:20694/WebApp";
var strsplit = str.Split(new char[] {':', '@', '/'};
var user = strsplit[1];
var password = strsplit[2];
```

Comment: You should expand on this answer and explain what you are doing and why. Simply showing code with no explanation doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current uri with the following approach

```
string uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; //as u targeted .net
```

Then parse it as a normal string.

You'll receive the following string :
`https://theuser:thepassword@localhost:20694/WebApp`

And you can get the information you are searching for by splitting the string into pieces.

```
        var uri = "https://theuser:thepassword@localhost:20694/WebApp";
        var currentUriSplit = uri.Split(new [] { ':', '@', '/' });
        var user = currentUriSplit[3];
        var password = currentUriSplit[4];
```

Comment: i was in hurry, i think it's uber obvious how you "parse" the string after that